Am a brahmachari and want to be a aajivan brahmachari.But I am confused whether to shave under my underwear .I would not mind the hairs but too itchy
I am a brahmachari and as mentioned want to be an aajivan brahmachari but am confused whether to shave under my underwear since the hair are too long and itchy .Should I shave it as an brahmachari?Plz answer as fast as you can.

What even is this question?

I read certain articles claiming a Brahmachari should not shave while some claim he should am confused.

Did the article cite any sources?

https://iskcondesiretree.com/forum/topics/brhmacharya
This one says not to shave

This one says to shave and to be kept clean.      https://iskcondesiretree.com/profiles/blogs/the-appearance-and-dress-of-a-brahmachari

are you associated with iskcon?

No just takes ideas for Brahmachari a from it and some other websites

@Which Sampradhaya do you belong to? Its better not to mix up things.

@Vatapatrashaayi is there some private chat option so I could get my answers quickly?

I have read that. Where does that say not to shave?

The one I shared for not to shave  see the 4 comment

@Vatapatrashaayi plz answer the question am waiting

I cannot see where it is stated to not shave. Sorry I cannot help you. If you know which Sutram your family/ancestors follow better look into that.

@Vatapatrashaayi please see 4th comment’s link and in that see SB 11.17.24

@Vatapatrashaayi give intsa I will tell the whole thing
